# Form elements should be at least 16px font-size to prevent mobile browsers from zooming when focused on iOS devices

Tags: bug, mobile-web, safari, ios

**TL;DR:** If mobile font-sizes in text inputs are at least `16px`, browsers on iOS devices won't zoom into the element when the user selects the input.

---

When navigating the Stack Overflow mobile website, selecting (or "focusing" on) some form elements such as inputs and text areas makes the browser zoom into the element.

> The browser will zoom if the font-size is less than `16px`

[Mobile font sizes in form elements should have at least `16px` font-size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394497/6817437). This applies to `input[type='text']`, `input[type='number']`, and `textarea` HTML elements.

Here is what I have found on stackoverflow.com with corresponding descriptions under the image:

[image: screenshot of stack overflow's Ask Question form on mobile view with Chrome DevTools]

Stack Overflow text inputs have font-size `13px`.

[image: screenshot of stack overflow's Ask Question multiline input on mobile view with Chrome DevTools]

There is a font-size of 14px in textareas.

[image]

In some communities I examined, the font size is as low as `12px`.

[image]

The above image is a mobile screenshot of the aforementioned 'zoom' that occurs after focusing on a Stack Overflow textarea. Notice that the screen is justified left, with the right side out of view.

From what I have found, browsers that behave this way are Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. I have only been able to test this on iOS.

This is an exceptionally disruptive behavior that renders the Stack Exchange forms very difficult to work with on an otherwise mobile-friendly website.

Comment: Interesting! I haven't seen this on Android, curious if anyone else has.

Comment: This is an OS-level choice that the Safari team made on iOS, so you won't see it on Android. You won't see it on Chrome for iOS either.

Comment: It appears that this topic has been debated before with Android, however I can't personally speak to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073396/disable-zoom-on-input-focus-in-android-webpage

Comment: @AaronShekey I do indeed experience this issue on Chrome for iOS (iPhone X, latest iOS).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up! I work on our design system called [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design). A ton of Stack Overflow inherits the CSS and markup from Stacks, though not as much as I’d like.

We want to fix this, but the problem with simply switching to `16px` is that compared to the rest of our interfaces, the input text is *huge*.

We’re tracking this [issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/382) on our repo and I’ve explored some technical solutions in a [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/383). You can take the `16px` inputs for a spin in a [test branch](https://deploy-preview-383--stacks.netlify.com/product/components/inputs).

To simply switch to `16px` and do it right, we’d want to change all the font sizes outside of the inputs as well, something we aren't gonna do to fix Safari’s intended behavior.

There might be a workaround that we haven’t found yet. For example, I found a solution that allows us to maintain zoom level on iOS, but it disabled pinch & zoom on Android. Shoot!

Comment: You _could_ use some css trickery to make the 16px only apply to iOS devices.

Comment: Not too familiar with CSS, but aren't media queries limited to screen metrics? If there's an OS check, wouldn't that involve JS?

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the reply and for sharing your progress. I realize this fix requires orchestrating much of the mobile experience with all of the spacing and text sizes. I do feel like the Stack Exchange mobile site is otherwise very functional.

Comment: @Zoe There are hacks available: [CSS media query to target only iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102792/css-media-query-to-target-only-ios-devices)